# Spring Batch | At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!` error while trying to run a simple Spring Batch application.

Relevant code & configuration:-

pom.xml:-

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Java configuration:-

```
/**
 * @author Kumar Sambhav Jain
 */
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("file:${baseDir}/config/properties/amqp.properties"),
        @PropertySource("file:${baseDir}/config/properties/mongodb.properties") })    
public class DelinquencyBatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor PersonItemProcessor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step")
                .Person, Person chunk(10).reader(reader())
                .processor(PersonItemProcessor()).writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
        PersonDelinquencyItemWriter writer = new PersonDelinquencyItemWriter();
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job delinquencyJob() throws Exception {
        final JobBuilder jobBuilder = jobBuilderFactory.get("delinquencyJob")
                .repository(getJobRepository());
        return jobBuilder.start(step())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Person> reader() {
        // Mongo based item reader comes here.
    }
}
```

JUnit:-

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { DelinquencyBatchConfiguration.class })
public class DelinquencyBatchTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // will trigger the job here !!
    }

}
```

While starting tht Junit I am getting this exception:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 39 more
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You somehow have to tell Spring that your mongodb models are in a certain package. Put a `ComponentScan` if you don't already have it and let Spring see your models.

Another alternative; if you don't use mongotemplate remove it.

Comment: MongoTemplate is needed to crate MongoItemReader.  The mongoTemplate do gets injected properly. So I don't think Mongo is the problem here. Does Spring Batch uses JPA (instead of plain JDBC dao) to CRUD job meta data ?

Comment: I think your Person pojo does not get scanned by Spring. 
What do you mean by job meta data?

Comment: Meta Data - JobInstance, JobExecution, StepExecution objects that are stored in DBMS (or Map implementation of JobRepository) to support job monitoring, restartability...

Comment: Spring Batch uses a Datasource directly, not JPA. Your context apparently configures something which requires JPA.